Relationship between vector spaces and affine sets: an example
I am working through Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimisation and thinking about the relationship between vector space's and affine sets. I have been trying to create my own example to work through and make sense of for my own notes and understanding.
I follow the idea that for some affine set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ then we can define a vector space $V = C - x_0, x_0 \in C$. However, if I start with some vector space, how can I transform this to an affine set without first knowing the set $C$ from which this vector resides? Am I able to arbitrarily choose an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
The example I have tried to work with is as follows. If I have the vector space $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ which is the $xy$ plane with the standard canonical basis vectors $(1, 0, 0)^T$ and $(0, 1, 0)^T$, then any vector $t \in T$ can be written as $(\alpha, \beta, 0), \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Could I choose say $x_0 = (0, 0, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (but this can be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and then define some new set $K = T - x_0 = \{(\alpha, \beta, 0) - (0, 0, 1)\} = \{(\alpha, \beta, -1)\}$ which is affine and no longer a vector space?
If then for any distinct points in the set $K$ say $k_1 = (\alpha_1, \beta_1, -1)$ and $k_2 = (\alpha_2, \beta_2, -1)$ then their affine combination yields
$$
\begin{align}
\theta_1 k_1 + (1 - \theta_1) k_2 = \ & \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_2 + \theta_1 (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)\\
\beta_2 + \theta_1 (\beta_1 + \beta_2)\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then this satisfies the requirement of the set $K$ and therefore proves the line is contained within $K$ and is thus an affine set.
As to why $K$ is not a vector space I am less sure. I know that to be a vector space, it must contain the zero vector and be closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Thus I assume any scalar multiplication translates the vector from the -1 plane and thus is not closed?
I would appreciate some help in confirming whether this line of reasoning is correct please. Thanks a lot!
